# Should I throw away decorations? (Sunni View)

Tags: sunni

There are many things which are purely decorative. For example, there are colorful badges which you just wear around because it is beautiful. Shoul I throw them away? THey seem expensive, but they're not something which I could give in charity because it's so useless etc.

Comment: I don't know how to make it clearer

Answer (score 3):

From 'Abdullah ibn Mas'ud radiallahu 'anhu who said that the Prophet sallallahu 'alayhi wa sallam said, "No one will enter Paradise who has an atom's weight of pride in his heart." A man said, "What if a man likes his clothes to look good and his shoes to look good?" He said, "**Allah is beautiful and loves beauty**. Pride means denying the truth and looking down on people." [Related by Muslim #131]

I dont think that its a problem as long as it does not catch excessive attention.

Please consider the guideline mentioned in [quran](http://quran.com/24/31)
i.e.

> not expose their adornment except to their husbands...
>
> let them not stamp their feet so as to reveal what they hide of their
> adornment.